# Update metainfo not found

Tags: python, predictionio

Done with installing PredictionIO and downloading an Engine Template. 
Using Python SDK.

```
       pio status
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting PredictionIO...
[INFO] [Console$] PredictionIO 0.9.4 is installed at /home/infoobjects/PredictionIO
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Console$] Apache Spark is installed at /home/infoobjects/PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.4.1
[INFO] [Console$] Apache Spark 1.4.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.3.0)
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: ELASTICSEARCH)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Model Data Backend (Source: LOCALFS)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Event Data Backend (Source: HBASE)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Test writing to Event Store (App Id 0)...
[INFO] [HBLEvents] The table pio_event:events_0 doesn't exist yet. Creating now...
[INFO] [HBLEvents] Removing table pio_event:events_0...
[INFO] [Console$] (sleeping 5 seconds for all messages to show up...)
[INFO] [Console$] Your system is all ready to go.
```

pio build
--verbose gives the following:

```
[INFO] [Console$] Using command '/home/infoobjects/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt' at the current working directory to build.
[INFO] [Console$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Console$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.9.4.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Console$] Going to run: /home/infoobjects/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency
[INFO] [Console$] Waiting for lock on /home/infoobjects/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...
[DEBUG] [UpgradeCheckRunner] Update metainfo not found. http://direct.prediction.io/0.9.4/build/org.template.recommendation.RecommendationEngine.json
```

and it just doesn't go any further.

Answer (score 0):

try removing locked file
rm sbt.boot.lock

or kill the sbt process

and then run the pio buil but also you can simply

just reboot your server and everything will be just fine

Comment: no its an answer its sbt file is locked and by rebooting it will get unlocked

Comment: The edit improved this; thanks.
It helps to explain just what was wrong, to show *how* a reboot fixes things.